# Program/Currency lookup table

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a lookup table so that I can determine by program and currency if the current day of a particular month is a holiday. I thought about building a calendar for each but that is going to get to big to deal with as programs may come and go.

A sample set of data would be something like:

```
Program | Currency | January | February | March | April     | May        | June | July | August | September | October | November | December
--------| ---------| --------| ---------| ------| -----------| ----------| -----| -----| -------| ----------| --------| ---------| -----------
Default | AUD      | 1, 27   | -        | -     | 10, 13     | -         | 8    | -    | -      | -         | 5       | -        | 25, 28
Default | CAD      | 1       | 17       | -     | 10         | 18        | -    | 1    | 3      | 7         | 12      | 11       | 25, 28
Default | CHF      | 1, 2    | -        | -     | 10, 13     | 1, 21     | 1    | -    | -      | -         | -       | -        | 25
Default | DKK      | 1       | -        | -     | 9, 10, 13  | 8, 21, 22 | 1, 5 | -    | -      | -         | -       | -        | 24, 25, 31
Default | EUR      | 1       | -        | -     | 10, 13     | 1         | -    | -    | -      | -         | -       | -        | 25
Default | GBP      | 1       | -        | -     | 10, 13     | 8, 25     | -    | -    | 31     | -         | -       | -        | 25, 28
```

I am not sure how to define this table.

Comment: A Calendar table seems to be **exactly** what you need here. For what you *appear* to have above it *assumes* that a month can only have 1 or 0 holidays; That's simply not true.

Comment: Actually, @Larnu, it looks like he's got comma-delimited lists of dates for each month.  Which is even worse :)

Comment: What values can `Program` have other than "Default"?

Comment: Yes each month of each program could have multiple holidays.  I started down the road with a calendar but was looking for an easier way since there may only be a max of 5 days that are actually holidays.

Comment: Program will have actual customer names, which can't show here.  But each program could have different currency.

Comment: A calendar table, *is* the easiest way, @Craig . The day a holiday falls on  *normally* changes each year. The above doesn't even consider that, meaning even if it's correct for this year, it's not next year, nor is it correct for last year.

Comment: I ***think*** I got your data in your question to be what it's actually meant to be. :/

Comment: And when your city/state/country shuts down because of a virus, what do you do? Not every week day is a "work" day just because there is no formal holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like:

```
Create Table Holiday_List
(
    ID Int
    , Program Varchar(50)
    , Currency Char(3)
    , Holiday_Date Date
)
```

Of course, you'll need an interface to maintain that table, but that should be pretty simple.